# Convolution of dependent discrete random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convolution

We have a set $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ of correlated discrete random variable with a given correlation matrix. How can one compute the sum $X_1 + X_2 + \cdots+ X_n$ knowing the probability mass functions of each variable and the correlation matrix?

Can you also please point me to some relevant papers to read ?

Thanks,
Bogdan.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  There's more to the joint probability mass function than the marginals and the correlations.  For example, consider two random variables
$X_1, X_2$, each uniformly distributed on $\{-1,0,1\}$, and with correlation $0$.
They could, for example, be independent, or they could have joint probability mass function
$$ \pmatrix{1/6 & 0 & 1/6\cr 0 & 1/3 & 0\cr 1/6 & 0 & 1/6\cr}$$
or
$$ \pmatrix{2/9 & 0 & 1/9\cr 0 & 1/9 & 2/9\cr 1/9 & 2/9 & 0\cr}$$
And each of these cases gives a different distribution to $X_1 + X_2$ .

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of way to approximate this summation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use dependent discrete convolution.
Here is a link of two papers:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7398177/
(Copula Based Dependent Discrete Convolution for Power System Uncertainty Analysis)

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8048488/
(An Efficient Approach to Power System Uncertainty Analysis With High-Dimensional Dependencies)

Hope it can be useful.
Regards,
Benyamin